# RESTful nested conventional routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, inherited-resources

I have the model:

- `User -1---n- Transaction(amount,description, date)`
- `User -1---n- TransactionImport -1---n- TransactonImportField(name,value)`

(personal expense tracking app).

What I want to achieve is this:

1. User opens URL and pastes the CSV with the list of transactions.
2. User submits it.
3. System extracts data from CSV into `TransactionImport` (row) + `TransactionImportField` (cell).
4. User can choose which column means what (amount, description, date) from the imported data in `TransactionImport(Field)`.
5. User click save and the system transfers `TransactionImport` into the Transaction.

What I can't seem to get right is the fact that step  3 creates multiple records of `TransactionImport` (and related `TransactionImportField`).

So doing `POST /transaction_imports?csv=abcd` is expected to produce one record if we would be RESTful. But the code is supposed to be something like this:

```
# TransactionImportsController
def create
  result = TransactionImports.parse(params[:csv])
  flash[:notice] = result.message
  redirect_to transaction_imports_path
end
```

I am probably approaching the task from a wrong angle as I feel that implementation doesn't fit in tp the [inherited_resources](http://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).

Could you please advise what would be the most conventional way of implementing this?

Thanks,
Dmytrii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST/HTTP has no expectation that doing POST will only create one record.  That maybe the default rails behaviour, but you should not constrain your design because of that.